# Don't know why it's rejecting my else statement

Tags: python, if-statement

```
drinks = 5
if drinks <= 2:
  print("Keep going buddy")
elif drinks == 3:
  print("I believe you've had enough, sir")
  else:
    print("stop")
```

This was the code I was trying to run, and it keeps giving me a syntax error with the "else" and I don't know why.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't put an image of code. Put the actual code. That allows us to copy/paste it and rerun it to recreate your issue.

Comment: Please post the code as *text* not as a screenshot.

Comment: Is it indented properly?

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong. Remove the space before the `else:`

Comment: Wdym? There is a space before the else that is why python is not registering the else.

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant after the `else :` sorry :).

Comment: This solved it, thanks! Can't believe something so simple was causing me so much frustration

Comment: Np! If this helped pls mark this as correct (check mark under the votes)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of your code is labeled as incorrect because an `else` statement and clause cannot exist without an `if` statement and clause preceding it. Since you have an `else` statement alone inside an `elif` clause, an error is thrown.

Likely this is just an issue with your indentation, which you need to be very careful about, since Python emphasizes whitespace. Here is the code I believe you meant to type:

```py
drinks = 5
if drinks <= 2:
    print("Keep going buddy")
elif drinks == 3:
    print("I believe you've had enough, sir")
else:
    print("stop")
```

Comment: Okay, thanks! It was an indentation issue with else. Normally instead of giving me a cagué "syntax error"  it tells me when I miss an indentation, usually. It didn't on this one and threw me for a loop